# What is a reason of getting error: "Unknown property '' on class MyBean"?

Tags: java, jasper-reports, javabeans

I've added DS to my report but I have an error

Why in error does not have a field on which the error occurs
I can not prescribe anything in the .jrxml

```
17:01:38,172 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:7051-1) net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Error retrieving field value from bean : 
17:01:38,172 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:7051-1)  at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRAbstractBeanDataSource.getBeanProperty(JRAbstractBeanDataSource.java:123)
17:01:38,172 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:7051-1)  at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRAbstractBeanDataSource.getFieldValue(JRAbstractBeanDataSource.java:96)
17:01:38,172 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:7051-1)  at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource.getFieldValue(JRBeanCollectionDataSource.java:100)
17:01:38,172 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:7051-1)  at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillDataset.setOldValues(JRFillDataset.java:1330)
17:01:38,172 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:7051-1)  at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillDataset.next(JRFillDataset.java:1231)
17:01:38,172 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:7051-1)  at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillDataset.next(JRFillDataset.java:1207)
17:01:38,172 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:7051-1)  at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.next(JRBaseFiller.java:1554)
17:01:38,172 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:7051-1)  at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReport(JRVerticalFiller.java:149)
17:01:38,172 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:7051-1)  at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:909)
17:01:38,172 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:7051-1)  at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:841)
17:01:38,172 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:7051-1)  at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.fill(JRFiller.java:88)
17:01:38,172 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:7051-1)  at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fill(JasperFillManager.java:653)
17:01:38,172 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:7051-1)  at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fill(JasperFillManager.java:569)
17:01:38,172 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:7051-1)  at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillReport(JasperFillManager.java:915)
17:01:38,173 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:7051-1)  at by.softclub.abank.admin.ui.reports.ReportBuilder.dataOutFromBeans(ReportBuilder.java:163)
17:01:38,173 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:7051-1)  at by.softclub.abank.admin.ui.reports.ReportBuilder.addByteDataToReport(ReportBuilder.java:65)
17:01:38,173 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:7051-1)  at by.softclub.abank.admin.ui.page.AbstractBasePage.getbuildReport(AbstractBasePage.java:197)
17:01:38,173 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:7051-1)  at by.softclub.abank.admin.ui.page.AbstractBasePage.printReport(AbstractBasePage.java:170)
17:01:38,173 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:7051-1)  at by.softclub.abank.admin.ui.page.UserInfoStatisticPage.printActiveUsersReport(UserInfoStatisticPage.java:152)
17:01:38,173 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:7051-1)  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
17:01:38,173 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:7051-1)  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
17:01:38,173 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:7051-1)  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
17:01:38,173 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:7051-1)  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
17:01:38,173 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:7051-1)  at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:258)
17:01:38,173 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:7051-1)  at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:278)
17:01:38,173 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:7051-1)  at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
17:01:38,173 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:7051-1)  at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:87)
17:01:38,173 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:7051-1)  at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
17:01:38,173 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:7051-1)  at org.primefaces.application.DialogActionListener.processAction(DialogActionListener.java:45)
17:01:38,175 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:7051-1)  at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
17:01:38,175 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:7051-1)  at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
17:01:38,175 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:7051-1)  at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
17:01:38,175 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:7051-1)  at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
17:01:38,175 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:7051-1)  at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
17:01:38,175 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:7051-1)  at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
17:01:38,175 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:7051-1)  at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:646)
17:01:38,175 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:7051-1)  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:295)
17:01:38,175 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:7051-1)  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
17:01:38,175 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:7051-1)  at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:98)
17:01:38,175 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:7051-1)  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:246)
17:01:38,175 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:7051-1)  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
17:01:38,175 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:7051-1)  at by.softclub.abank.admin.ui.faces.UrlFilter.doFilter(UrlFilter.java:118)
17:01:38,175 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:7051-1)  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:246)
17:01:38,175 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:7051-1)  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
17:01:38,175 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:7051-1)  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:230)
17:01:38,175 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:7051-1)  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:149)
17:01:38,175 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:7051-1)  at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:169)
17:01:38,175 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:7051-1)  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:145)
17:01:38,175 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:7051-1)  at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:97)
17:01:38,176 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:7051-1)  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:102)
17:01:38,176 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:7051-1)  at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:336)
17:01:38,176 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:7051-1)  at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:856)
17:01:38,176 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:7051-1)  at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:653)
17:01:38,176 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:7051-1)  at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:920)
17:01:38,176 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:7051-1)  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
17:01:38,176 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:7051-1) Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: Unknown property '' on class 'class by.softclub.common.entity.UserBPSWrapper'
17:01:38,176 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:7051-1)  at org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtilsBean.getSimpleProperty(PropertyUtilsBean.java:1322)
17:01:38,176 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:7051-1)  at org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtilsBean.getNestedProperty(PropertyUtilsBean.java:770)
17:01:38,176 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:7051-1)  at org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtilsBean.getProperty(PropertyUtilsBean.java:846)
17:01:38,176 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:7051-1)  at org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtils.getProperty(PropertyUtils.java:426)
17:01:38,176 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:7051-1)  at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRAbstractBeanDataSource.getBeanProperty(JRAbstractBeanDataSource.java:111)
17:01:38,176 ERROR [stderr] (http-/0.0.0.0:7051-1)  ... 54 more
```

So my bean

```
public class UserBPSWrapper implements Serializable, IWrapper {

    private String id;
    private String numberSubdivision;
    private String fioAdmin;
    private Date dateReg;
    private String fioClient;
    private String numberPhone;
    private String numberPassport;
    private Date dateRegClient;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getNumberSubdivision() {
        return numberSubdivision;
    }

    public void setNumberSubdivision(String numberSubdivision) {
        this.numberSubdivision = numberSubdivision;
    }

    public String getFioAdmin() {
        return fioAdmin;
    }

    public void setFioAdmin(String fioAdmin) {
        this.fioAdmin = fioAdmin;
    }

    public Date getDateReg() {
        return dateReg;
    }

    public void setDateReg(Date dateReg) {
        this.dateReg = dateReg;
    }

    public String getFioClient() {
        return fioClient;
    }

    public void setFioClient(String fioClient) {
        this.fioClient = fioClient;
    }

    public String getNumberPhone() {
        return numberPhone;
    }

    public void setNumberPhone(String numberPhone) {
        this.numberPhone = numberPhone;
    }

    public String getNumberPassport() {
        return numberPassport;
    }

    public void setNumberPassport(String numberPassport) {
        this.numberPassport = numberPassport;
    }

    public Date getDateRegClient() {
        return dateRegClient;
    }

    public void setDateRegClient(Date dateRegClient) {
        this.dateRegClient = dateRegClient;
    }
}
```

I call report

```
JRDataSource dataSource = createReportDataSource(reportRows);
String jasperReportName = newPath + templateXML + ".jasper";

jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReportName, reportParametersMap, dataSource);

private JRDataSource createReportDataSource(Collection reportRows) {
    JRDataSource dataSource;

    if (reportRows == null || reportRows.size() == 0) {
        dataSource = new JREmptyDataSource();
    } else {
        dataSource = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(reportRows);
    }
    return dataSource;
}
setListToReportDetails((List<UserBPSWrapper>) dataBPSModel.getWrappedData());
```

My JRXML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="Subdevelopers" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="bfa8e4d4-05e1-4c4c-85de-9feb417ff0eb">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="One Empty Record"/>
    <parameter name="subdivisionName" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="dateFrom" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="dateTo" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="reportDate" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="clientsCountText" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="numberSubdivision" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="fioAdmin" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="dateReg" class="java.util.Date"/>
    <field name="fioClient" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="numberPhone" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="numberPassport" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="dateRegClient" class="java.util.Date">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <title>
        <band height="85" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="0" y="0" width="380" height="14" uuid="cded2592-f09e-4c61-89d6-f5e5d143035e"/>
                <textElement markup="none">
                    <font fontName="SansSerif" size="10" isBold="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{subdivisionName}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="14" width="90" height="14" uuid="c90da0c8-1336-4dc3-a021-f0e3ae942b2d">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement>
                    <font fontName="SansSerif" size="10"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[РџРµСЂРёРѕРґ РѕС‚С‡РµС‚Р° СЃ:]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="90" y="14" width="70" height="14" uuid="53044afe-bd20-42a6-97fb-e6b8b5e81b83"/>
                <textElement markup="none">
                    <font fontName="SansSerif" size="10" isBold="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{dateFrom}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="160" y="14" width="20" height="14" uuid="10a6a7db-dd2a-4bb6-8f06-25a03e8bd5d9">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement>
                    <font fontName="SansSerif" size="10"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[РїРѕ]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="180" y="14" width="70" height="14" uuid="878bcb56-dc60-4bb5-9909-73506e8be23e"/>
                <textElement markup="none">
                    <font fontName="SansSerif" size="10" isBold="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{dateTo}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="28" width="380" height="14" uuid="6a7930c5-5605-493f-8dc4-cf3d60f9131a">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement>
                    <font fontName="SansSerif" size="10"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Р‘Р°РЅРє: РћРђРћ "Р‘РџРЎ-РЎР±СЂРµР±Р°РЅРє"]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="42" width="180" height="14" uuid="8e29e107-6761-48f6-9ce9-3a430f2ad173">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                </reportElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Р”Р°С‚Р° Рё РІСЂРµРјСЏ С„РѕСЂРјРёСЂРѕРІР°РЅРёСЏ РѕС‚С‡РµС‚Р°:]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="180" y="42" width="200" height="14" uuid="c0532bd1-edbc-4d78-b126-239cdfd3b818"/>
                <textElement markup="none">
                    <font fontName="SansSerif" size="10" isBold="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{reportDate}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </title>
    <columnHeader>
        <band height="31" splitType="Stretch">
            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
            <rectangle>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="20" height="31" uuid="fab33adb-f537-46e1-ae19-aed14e0d553a"/>
            </rectangle>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="20" height="30" uuid="8b0c0311-2893-404d-a5f6-759c71585b39">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="8"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[в„–]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <rectangle>
                <reportElement x="20" y="0" width="100" height="31" uuid="4c6d0de7-16be-4584-a292-b323d1765921"/>
            </rectangle>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="20" y="0" width="100" height="30" uuid="90ea0ab1-7105-4ae0-8a27-74db2a3d5a88">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="pixel"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="8"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Р¤РРћ Р°РґРјРёРЅРёСЃС‚СЂР°С‚РѕСЂР°]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <rectangle>
                <reportElement x="120" y="0" width="70" height="31" uuid="b7cdcd71-072e-4406-bebd-8b8f29b145f3"/>
            </rectangle>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="120" y="0" width="70" height="30" uuid="17cc09fb-826a-4fc3-bf1f-8f56e54cfbd3">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="8"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Р”Р°С‚Р° СЂРµРіРёСЃС‚СЂР°С†РёРё]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <rectangle>
                <reportElement x="190" y="0" width="100" height="31" uuid="76f7b8c5-8418-4cb6-a7a1-17afbce4cfbf">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="pixel"/>
                </reportElement>
            </rectangle>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="190" y="0" width="100" height="30" uuid="9366a903-3ba0-492b-b2b9-1a5af4080975">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="8"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Р¤РРћ РєР»РёРµРЅС‚Р°]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <rectangle>
                <reportElement x="290" y="0" width="100" height="31" uuid="09f7a047-ab01-4e01-a268-5dcbcd2fae49">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="pixel"/>
                </reportElement>
            </rectangle>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="290" y="0" width="100" height="30" uuid="f31660cc-44c3-4646-a5e5-71a7c0935520">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="8"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[РќРѕРјРµСЂ РјРѕР±РёР»СЊРЅРѕРіРѕ]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <rectangle>
                <reportElement x="390" y="0" width="100" height="31" uuid="ac78bb73-ac1c-49b2-ba4f-292f2453dec4">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="pixel"/>
                </reportElement>
            </rectangle>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="390" y="0" width="100" height="30" uuid="f76e2870-bd7a-4099-9a53-5916974b7fe2">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="8"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Р›/Рќ РїР°СЃРїРѕСЂС‚Р°]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <rectangle>
                <reportElement x="490" y="0" width="70" height="31" uuid="c932d60f-efe1-421d-8fbe-a66f6d09eb10"/>
            </rectangle>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="490" y="0" width="70" height="30" uuid="de94e44b-9faa-4835-81be-651662d3a0a3">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="8"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Р”Р°С‚Р° СЂРµРіРёСЃС‚СЂР°С†РёРё РєР»РёРµРЅС‚РѕРј]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </columnHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="31" splitType="Stretch">
            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
            <rectangle>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="20" height="31" uuid="944528be-a403-4ed1-8ece-6c6d40cece23"/>
            </rectangle>
            <rectangle>
                <reportElement x="20" y="0" width="100" height="31" uuid="d65b1141-6bf4-431e-996a-a56ee713e7aa"/>
            </rectangle>
            <rectangle>
                <reportElement x="120" y="0" width="70" height="31" uuid="8440dbcb-221e-452a-9188-322c0fc00bdd"/>
            </rectangle>
            <rectangle>
                <reportElement x="190" y="0" width="100" height="31" uuid="03976249-b504-4218-b151-06aa198fe1bd">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="pixel"/>
                </reportElement>
            </rectangle>
            <rectangle>
                <reportElement x="290" y="0" width="100" height="31" uuid="28dbda54-1653-4559-b5ea-fcee2fa497b2">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="pixel"/>
                </reportElement>
            </rectangle>
            <rectangle>
                <reportElement x="390" y="0" width="100" height="31" uuid="be18db82-9a46-4e54-b2d1-98f2bc66af77">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="pixel"/>
                </reportElement>
            </rectangle>
            <rectangle>
                <reportElement x="490" y="0" width="70" height="31" uuid="0c336ccd-ea62-4e10-b521-69b85599592d"/>
            </rectangle>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="0" y="0" width="20" height="30" uuid="d0d3ca75-e0ed-4605-9b35-9e25a9d61b89"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle" markup="none">
                    <font fontName="SansSerif" size="8" isBold="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{numberSubdivision}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="20" y="0" width="100" height="30" uuid="15faac99-3883-445e-b399-80aed7b8639e"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle" markup="none">
                    <font fontName="SansSerif" size="8" isBold="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{fioAdmin}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="120" y="0" width="70" height="30" uuid="350cccbb-0c58-4136-8306-278195115415"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle" markup="none">
                    <font fontName="SansSerif" size="8" isBold="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{dateReg}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="190" y="0" width="100" height="30" uuid="d35bafcc-3666-4fdb-a3e3-dfd5242bc7df"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle" markup="none">
                    <font fontName="SansSerif" size="8" isBold="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{fioClient}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="290" y="0" width="100" height="30" uuid="29f916c0-00a5-4d08-8c69-5673dbb36e59"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle" markup="none">
                    <font fontName="SansSerif" size="8" isBold="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{numberPhone}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="390" y="0" width="100" height="30" uuid="f24050a4-70c1-4fdb-ba88-03c0ea49445c"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle" markup="none">
                    <font fontName="SansSerif" size="8" isBold="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{numberPassport}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="490" y="0" width="70" height="30" uuid="e47a9534-4964-4208-8e0d-d6e03c65754e"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle" markup="none">
                    <font fontName="SansSerif" size="8" isBold="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{dateRegClient}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
    <pageFooter>
        <band height="70" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="0" y="0" width="560" height="24" uuid="4608c8a8-f63c-4b04-8c48-9bdb0a8f085a">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement markup="none">
                    <font fontName="SansSerif" size="10" isBold="false"/>
                    <paragraph leftIndent="240"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{clientsCountText}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="240" height="14" uuid="05f5423b-164a-4754-acca-5c064adef821">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                </reportElement>
                <text><![CDATA[РљРѕР»РёС‡РµСЃС‚РІРѕ Р·Р°СЂРµРіРёСЃС‚СЂРёСЂРѕРІР°РЅРЅС‹С… РєР»РёРµРЅС‚РѕРІ, РІСЃРµРіРѕ:]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="30" width="80" height="14" uuid="d90bb3fc-d0ff-44a9-ba75-bdcccd3ddf87">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                </reportElement>
                <text><![CDATA[РћС‚С‡РµС‚ РїСЂРѕРІРµСЂРёР» ]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <line>
                <reportElement x="80" y="44" width="100" height="1" uuid="3d0fceff-a0dd-4b79-93aa-aa5e9158ef27"/>
                <graphicElement>
                    <pen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid"/>
                </graphicElement>
            </line>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="180" y="30" width="10" height="14" uuid="fe722733-55c0-4cae-b24d-5669fc15c2ba">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                </reportElement>
                <text><![CDATA[(]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="290" y="30" width="10" height="14" uuid="3d078cf1-0d6b-4083-8652-204e1ad15f99">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                </reportElement>
                <text><![CDATA[)]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <line>
                <reportElement x="190" y="44" width="100" height="1" uuid="4a4d46de-8544-4f79-bc2b-0356e9468edf"/>
                <graphicElement>
                    <pen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid"/>
                </graphicElement>
            </line>
        </band>
    </pageFooter>
</jasperReport>
```

Comment: The reason is: `Unknown property '' on class 'class by.softclub.common.entity.UserBPSWrapper'`. Try to remove: `<fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>` in *numberSubdivision* and *dateRegClient* fields declaration

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `dateRegClient` field in the report has an empty `fieldDescription`.  Field descriptions are used to map field to bean property names, whence the error.

Removing the field description or setting it to `dateRegClient` should get rid of the error.

Comment: @LeshaRB consider always to accept an answer when you like if the answered worked, accepting is the green check next to the question under the votes, learn more about accepting answers in [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [accepted-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)